# Reference request: Kuratowski convergence and convergence in Hausdorff metric

Tags: general-topology

On [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_convergence) Wiki page, it claims that (in 4th sentences in related concept section)

> For compact metric spaces X, Kuratowski convergence coincides with
> both convergence in Hausdorff metric and Vietoris topology.

I am wondering can anybody give me a reference where it proves this claim? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in Topics on Analysis by Luigi Ambrosio & Paolo Tilli, the full proof is on pages 73 and 74.